# VBA entering data and submittin javascript form

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, internet-explorer-9

Hi I am really struggling with submitting a form in Internet Expolrer through Excel macro. The "Search" button here doesn't have "ID". This is why I can't use .Click method for "serialNumber" Id. Could you help with Visual Basic code. how to enter data in the window and click "search" button by vba code. Thx.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="form" data-bind="enterkey: search">
<form action="https://somewebpage.com/application/serialnumbersearch/Search" method="get">
<label>
Serial number:
</label>
<input name="serialNumber" id="serialNumber" type="text" data-bind="value: serialNumber">
<input type="submit" value="Search" data-bind="click: search, disable: isLoading()">  
</form></div>
```

[image]

My code:

```
Private Sub IE_Autiomation()
Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim iframe As HTMLDocument
' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.navigate       "https://somepage.com/Tools/Pages/Serialnumbersearch.aspx"



' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."
Set iframe = IE.document.getElementById("alexIFRAME").contentWindow.document
Set objCollection = iframe.getElementsByTagName("input")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "serialNumber" Then

        ' Set text for search
        objCollection(i).Value = "excel vba"

    Else
        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
           objCollection(i).Name = "" Then

            ' "Search" button is found
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)

        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
objElement.Click    ' click button to search

' Wait while IE re-loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

' Show IE
IE.Visible = True

' Clean up
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual URL and what data you need to retrieve? XHR may be more suitable.

Comment: To access this webpage it is needed to have a login and password. I manage to make a code which will eneter my data to textbox named "serialNumber" but then the button "SEARCH" is frozen, not reacting to clicking, even manual - with  mouse. The is available in the post below.

Comment: What version of IE can you manually use this page with?  Research FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION, as CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") defaults to like ver. 8

Comment: I use Internet Expolor 11.036. What is XHR? Could you give me some link (in english) to read & learn about it. Thx.